# Uniformly continuous and bounded set.

Tags: real-analysis

> $\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ continuous and $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ a bounded set. Prove that $f \vert _{X}$ is uniformly continuous.

$\textbf{My proof}$:

Let $\{x_k\},\{y_k\} \in X$ sequences such that

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty}(x_k-y_k)=0 $$

We will prove that :

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} z_k=\lim_{k\to \infty}(f(x_k)-f(y_k))=0 $$

Indeed, let $\{z_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_1} $ a subsequence of $\{z_k\}$ where $\mathbb{N}_1 \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and :

$$ \lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_1} z_k = b\in \mathbb{R}^n \ldots (*)$$

How $x_k \in X, \forall k\in \mathbb{N}_1$ exists a subsequence $\{x_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2}$ of $\{x_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}_1}$ $(\mathbb{N}_2 \subseteq \mathbb{N}_1)$ such that :

$$ \lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} x_k = a \in \mathbb{R}^m $$

Furthermore :

$$ \{y_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} =\{y_k-x_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} + \{x_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} $$

So :

$$ \lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} y_k = a \in \mathbb{R}^m $$

For the continuity of $f$ :

$$ \lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} f(x_k) = \lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} f(y_k) = f(a) \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

So, finally :

$$ \lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2}z_k =\lim_{k\in \mathbb{N}_2} (f(x_k)-f(y_k))= 0 $$

For $(*)$ : $b=0$, then any subsequence of $\{z_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}_1}$ that converges makes it to $0$.

So :

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} z_k =0$$

> $\textbf{Note:}$ $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if : $\forall \{x_k\}, \{y_k\}\in X$ such that $\{x_k-y_k\} \rightarrow 0$ implies that $\{f(x_k)-f(y_k)\} \rightarrow 0$

My proof is correct?, thanks!

Comment: Why not use a much simpler argument using the fact that the closure of $X$ is compact and any continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Because I could not use compact yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is absolutely correct (sorry for any confusion, no gripes to be had).

---

A counterexample (when $f$ is not assumed to be already continuous on all of $\mathbb R$); $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$. To see this, we take $\varepsilon=1$ and consider the sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty:=\left\{\frac1{n}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$  and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty:=\left\{\frac1{n+1}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$. So we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n-y_n|=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=0, \text{ BUT} \\ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=1 \text{ (actually true for every } n \in \mathbb N\text{)}.$$